# No change in design view from property info, before running the application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When I change directly from property info a dependency property, I don't have the result immediately in my design view defore I run the application.

```
   <local:OnOffToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,34,0,0" x:Name="onOffToggleButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" StateOf4="3" GotFocus="onOffToggleButton1_GotFocus" Loaded="onOffToggleButton1_Loaded" />


public class OnOffToggleButton : Control// ToggleButton
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateOf4Property;

    static OnOffToggleButton()
    {

        OnOffToggleButton.StateOf4Property = DependencyProperty.Register("StateOf4", typeof(int), typeof(OnOffToggleButton));
    }

    public int StateOf4
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(OnOffToggleButton.StateOf4Property);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OnOffToggleButton.StateOf4Property, value);
        }          
    }
}
```

}

here is default value, template and style for my toggle button

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>                   
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:OnOffToggleButton}" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse x:Name="btnEllipse" StrokeThickness="2"  Stroke="DarkBlue" Width="128" Height="131">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.3,0.2" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Azure" Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>

                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="StateOf4" Value="1">
            <Setter TargetName="btnEllipse" Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.3,0.2" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="GreenYellow" Offset="1.1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="StateOf4" Value="2">
            <Setter TargetName="btnEllipse" Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.3,0.2" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="BlueViolet" Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Pink" Offset="1.1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="StateOf4" Value="3">
            <Setter TargetName="btnEllipse" Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.3,0.2" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Maroon" Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Pink" Offset="1.1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:OnOffToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Can you help me, please! :)

Comment: That is a lot of code; can you provide just the relevant code and be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I think triggers does not work in VS designer.

Workaround would be to use VisualStateManager and translate StateOf4 values to different visual states. That will work in designer as well.